# WebStart Launching attempts to find jar locally

Tags: java, java-web-start

To start off, I am launching a jar over Java webstart and it has worked fine on all browsers in my lab. An issue arises where, at a customer site with all their various IT restrictions, it only seems to work on Chrome but fails on IE and Safari browsers.

I launch the jnlp via an html file through the browser. The link I used was:

```
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('launch.jnlp');">Launch Application</a>Application</a>
```

I attempted to change this to:

```
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <a href="http://IPADDR:8080/PLCPar/launch.jnlp">Launch Application</a>
```

Reason being is my company has another webstart app that works in all browsers at this customer's site and their link looks more like the replacement.

So what I'm seeing with the replacement is that the JNLP is not being launched from the browser but instead being downloaded locally. When launched it attempts to find the jar relative to where it was downloaded. Not sure what I'm missing and why it is trying to download instead of launch via webstart?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with this a lot in the past. So couple of rules in general needs to be followed in order to go smoothly.

- make sure your URL where jnlp sits is not cached, maybe you need to develop some Pragma No Cache, etc. things on the server so it doesn't treat it as static resource
- clear cache of JNLP, see https://www.java.com/en/download/help/plugin_cache.xml
- Check the shortcut icon on Desktop(assuming OS is windows), sometimes it creates crappy shortcuts, you can edit the shortcut and put always your URL, not the cached one
- if that doesn't help you need to upgrade or downgrade java, depending on the case

In the past I even made special script which was downloaded and executed on client machine to fix the shortcuts .lnk files because of this buggy java functionality.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. I tried to clear the cache with no luck. I'd prefer to launch directly from the HTML. I've tried several version of java 8. I was thinking the issue revolved around it downloading the jnlp instead of just launching it.